# Python continue not properly in loop

Tags: python

I am working with BeautifulSoup and I keep getting an error continue not properly in loop. So I deleted the continue and then I get an invalid syntax error for my print statement. I am running BS4 and Python 2.7.5 all help greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.html"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
for link in tr.find_all('a'):
    fulllink = link.get('href')
    print fulllink #print in terminal to verify results

tds = tr.find_all("td")


try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. 
   names = str(tds[0].get_text()) 
   years = str(tds[1].get_text())
   positions = str(tds[2].get_text())
   parties = str(tds[3].get_text())
   states = str(tds[4].get_text())
   congress = tds[5].get_text()

except:
  print "bad tr string"
  continue 

print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress
```

Comment: What do you expect the `continue` to *do* here?

Comment: Your code isn't formatted correctly. Can you format it as it should? @MartijnPieters I believe the whole part of the code below the first `for` is wrongly nested.

Comment: Is everything after `for tr in trs:` supposed to be in that loop? Please indent accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have the error, I believe that you probably really have the wrong indent in your file. Your code should look like this probably:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.html"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:

    for link in tr.find_all('a'):
        fulllink = link.get('href')
        print fulllink #print in terminal to verify results

    tds = tr.find_all("td")


    try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. 
       names = str(tds[0].get_text()) 
       years = str(tds[1].get_text())
       positions = str(tds[2].get_text())
       parties = str(tds[3].get_text())
       states = str(tds[4].get_text())
       congress = tds[5].get_text()

       print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress

    except exc:
      print "bad tr string"
```

In python, each block of code should be nested with indent using tabs/space. Mixing them isn't good.

In your code, you have a first for loop that will walk all tr and a second that prints all urls.

But you forgot to indent the first block that should be inside the for loop.

## Edit

Also you don't have to use continue in your case. Check my edit to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation looks off on print/continue.  If it is off, the except: will look like it's empty, which I'm not sure is something Python is happy with.

Try commenting out everything not related to the try/except and see if it still gives you the error.